# Error: inserting data into hana from oracle using dblink

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to insert into hana database from oracle using dblink.I am getting the below error:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-20001: ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a
> non-Oracle system returned this message: [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB
> SO][HDBODBC] General error;12000 user-defined error: line 2 col 142
> (at pos 277): [12000] (range 3) user-defined error exception: no table
> change allowed {HY000,NativeErr = 12000} ORA-06512: at
> "POP_REMOTE_TABLES", line 58 ORA-06512: at line 1

---

Below is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VIEW_TEST_DYNAMIC
(
  TRANS_OUT
)
AS 
    select 'insert into test_dynamic@dblink_hana(cust_id,address) values ('||cust_id||','''||address||''')' as trans_out from
    (
    select 10 cust_id,'9 Help Street, Level 4' address from dual union all
    select 11 cust_id,'22 Victoria Street' address from dual union all
    select 12 cust_id,'1495 Franklin Str.' address from dual union all
    select 13 cust_id,'30 Hasivim St.,Petah-Tikva' address from dual union all
    select 14 cust_id,'2 Jakaranda St' address from dual union all
    select 15 cust_id,'61, Science Park Rd' address from dual union all
    select 16 cust_id,'61, Social park road.' address from dual union all
    select 17 cust_id,'Av. Hermanos Escobar 5756' address from dual union all
    select 18 cust_id,'Ave. Hermanos Escobar 5756' address from dual union all
    select 19 cust_id,'8000 W FLORISSANT Ave.' address from dual union all
    select 20 cust_id,'8600 MEMORIAL PKWY SW' address from dual union all
    select 21 cust_id,'8200 FLORISSANTMEMORIALWAYABOVE SW' address from dual union all
    select 22 cust_id,'8600 MEMORIALFLORISSANT PKWY SW.' address from dual
    ) t1;
    
create table test_remote(local_table_name varchar2(50));
insert into test_remote values('VIEW_TEST_DYNAMIC');

procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pop_remote_tables(p_table_name in varchar2 default 'ALL') as
l_cursor sys_refcursor;
l_trans_out varchar2(32000) := NULL;
l_processed_cnt number := 0;
cursor tab_cur is
select upper(local_table_name) local_table_name from test_remote where active_yn='Y' and
upper(local_table_name) = nvl(decode(upper(p_table_name),'ALL',NULL,upper(p_table_name)),upper(local_table_name));

BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Started');
    for tab_rec in tab_cur
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Started processing:'||tab_rec.local_table_name);
        l_processed_cnt := 0;
        open l_cursor for 'select trans_out from ' || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(tab_rec.local_table_name);
        loop
            fetch l_cursor into l_trans_out;
            exit when l_cursor%notfound;
            execute immediate l_trans_out;
            l_processed_cnt := l_processed_cnt + 1;
        end loop;
        commit;
        close l_cursor;
        dbms_output.put_line( 'No of records Inserted:' || l_processed_cnt);
    end loop;

dbms_output.put_line('Ended');
   
EXCEPTION
    when others then
      raise_application_error(-20001, sqlerrm);
END;
/
sho err;
```

Can someone please help how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Remove EXCEPTION entirely, it is useless (the way you use it). Then run the procedure again, but this time Oracle will point to exact error place (line and column). Maybe then it'll be clearer what's wrong.

Comment: @Littlefoot I removed the EXCEPTION and reran the procedure but still, I am getting the same error. first, I ran this procedure for local tables. it works well for local database.

Comment: Error is the same, but **line** is not. Previously, Oracle reported line in which RAISE was ... well, *raised*, and it was line #58. Without the EXCEPTION, which line does it report now?